# Vue,js has $refs undefined in console but works in $nextTick. Why console shows the values but returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debugging, console

I'm a bit confused about $refs behavior in my code.

```
      console.log("> Value "+e.code);
      console.log(them.$refs)
      val = parseInt(them.$refs[e.code][0].value);
```

The first line shows  *e.code* is defined as *angle*
The second one shows the $refs.angle[0].value exists

But the  third gets this error:  *Cannot read property '0' of undefined"*

here the output:

[image]

If I run this code inside  *this.$nextTick(() => {...})* it works properly.

My question is why the console show and undefined for a defined value?

Comment: Where are you calling this code that accesses `this.$refs`?

Comment: It's a nested into a forEach in a method called by @change. The strange is only for an object. The other one was not affected by this issue. Note, in my code I replaced "this" inside the cycle by a clone of this.